# Adjective/ Collocation with 'Caution:' -- Why does 'huge' sound odd?

Tags: adjectives, collocation, uncountable-nouns

Simon Johnson, Scottish Political Editor, *[The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/nicola-sturgeon/11590702/Nicola-Sturgeon-Im-treating-exit-poll-with-huge-caution.html)* UK, 11:08PM BST 07 May 2015:

> *Nicola Sturgeon: I'm treating exit poll with huge caution*
>   Nicola Sturgeon tweeted: “I’d treat the exit poll with **HUGE** caution. I’m hoping for a good night but I think 58 seats is unlikely!”

*Caution* is a mass noun. While reliable sources suggest possible adjectives/ collocations with *caution* as *considerable, extreme, great, utmost, excessive, due,* I would think *a huge **amount of** caution* may be fine as well. However, *huge caution* sounds rather odd to me.

Is that about grammar, semantics, usage or just a case of being unidiomatic phrasing?

Comment: It's a tweet. Don't overthink it. Just someone trying to be creative in 140 characters.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction You got it right, though I was not unaware of it. My point was purely academic. I still think there's something amiss with *huge caution.*

Comment: It's common for people to replace `great` with `huge` for further emphasis. [Great caution](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great+caution&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreat%20caution%3B%2Cc0) has a pretty solid usage history. I figured the author thought she could replace `great` with `huge` is this particular instance and didn't give it too much thought.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Let's leave the author alone. We are dealing with the language here.

Comment: No offence intended. I'm trying to say that in tweets, people tend to be a little less cautious with the proper usages than in standard publications. Like I said, it could be an instance of creativity rather than established usage patterns.

Answer (score 1):

[Huge](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/huge) can be used with mass nouns, it is just not generally associated with the term *caution* (see Ngram).

> - Of exceedingly great scope or nature: *the huge influence of the Hellenic world.* (AHD)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=huge%20caution&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuge%20caution%3B%2Cc0) *huge caution* - [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=huge%20caution%2Chuge%20influence&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuge%20caution%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chuge%20influence%3B%2Cc0) *huge caution vs huge influence*

You are right in saying it sounds odd becauce *huge* in the sentence is actually used to suggest   *exceedingly great size, extent, or quantity*, probably to stress with an 'unusual' construction the need to be very, very, careful about the exit poll (and given the results this morning he was right!!)

We could say, as you suggest, it is an unidiomatic use of *huge*.

Answer (score 0):

Over the last couple of centuries we have apparently become less cautious, but "huge caution" was never much used. The phrase which springs to mind in the quote you provided is "extreme caution", and n-gram seems to agree https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=huge+caution%2C+extreme+caution%2C+great+caution&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuge%20caution%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextreme%20caution%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20caution%3B%2Cc0
[image]
It should be noted that the scale of the image here hides the occurrence of a few instances in the 1820 - 1840 period.